# Java - OpenCV java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java, spring, opencv

I'm trying to make an app that takes pictures using the webcam. I'm using OpenCV with Java.
This is the method I'm using:

```
public String sacarFoto(){

    //conecta con la webcam
    VideoCapture cap = new VideoCapture(0);

    //variable donde se va a guardar la imagen
    Mat image = new Mat();
    cap.retrieve(image);

    //establece el path de la foto
    String foto="C:/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE/resources/captura.jpg";
    //guarda la foto (este archivo se pisa cada vez que se vuelve a correr el reconocimiento)
    Highgui.imwrite(foto, image);

    //libera la referencia a la webcam
    cap.release();

    //devuelve el path a la foto
    return foto;
}
```

When I try to run it I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture
```

I know that the library is working because I tried to use the face recognition functionality and it worked perfectly.

Any suggestions of what could be missing?

EDDITED

So, I tried running that part of the code as a java application (instead of 'run on server') and it works fine. So I assume the problem is in the spring dependencies. This is what I have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9-4</version>
</dependency>
```

but it's not working. Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the library which contains the class "org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture" is in the classpath. If maven is being used, add this jar as a dependency.

Comment: I added the OpenCV library, and it's working fine. At least other functionalities (like recognizing a face in a picture) are. The problem appears when I try to take a picture using the web cam

Comment: Kalyan, can you please explain me how to add the jar as a dependency?

Comment: Hi Teresita, please try the below  dependency including the scope for the library  and recompile your project <dependency>
    <groupId>nu.pattern</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId><scope>provided</scope>
    <version>2.4.9-4</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I tried that, and it's still not working... I'm geting this message: "Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libopencv_java249 in java.library.path"